# Change div content after loading it with ajax load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

*index.html* page :

[image]

[image]

I am loading the *new.html* page using ajax load method and then tried to change the content of the `div#rr` but it did not work!

any solution ?

Comment: Please post some of your code so we can help you

Comment: Debug it! check your ajax request and result! What error is coming?? Can you show your code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why your code `$('#rr').html('modfied');` is not working because you are calling the change before jquery ajax.load() method is able to load the content from your `new.html` and as result your id `#rr` is not found. So, instead of calling the modify code after the load statement call the modifying statement in your load()'s complete() 
as:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.container').load('new.html', function () {
                $('#rr').html('modfied');
            });
        });
```

and please go through the jquery documentation for more info on how to use the functions [Jquery Documentation for Load() funciton](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the function inside the ajax call function.

```
$('.container').load('new.html',function(){
      $('#rr').html('modified') 
});
```

next time please do not put image for code.